# A panel is not being dragable - Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a project and using Bootstrap and Jquery Ui for the frontend.
 The **index.php** File is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="weatherModule/weatherFetcherForIndex.js"></script>
        <?php
            include "resources/resources.php";
            echo $bootstrap;
            include "NewsFeed/CnnNewsFeed.php";
            $cnn = new CnnNewsFeed("world");
            $feed = $cnn->getRss();
            echo $jquery_ui;
        ?>
        <script src="resources/dragable.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    //navbar
    echo $navbar;
    $items = $feed->channel->item;
    ?>
    <div id="temp" style="width: 30%; height: 7%; margin-top: 6.5%;">

    </div>
    <?php
    echo $cnnNewsHeader;
    for($i = 0; $i <= 2+1; $i++)
    {
        echo "<a href='". $items[$i]->guid ."' class='list-group-item'>
            <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>" . $items[$i]->title . "</h4>
                    <p class='list-group-item-text'>" . $items[$i]->description . "</p>
                </a>";
    }
    echo $cnnNewsFooter;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could just skip the weather part which is working perfectly. And that **resources/resources.php** file is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: root
 * Date: 11/7/15
 * Time: 10:42 AM
 */
$jquery_ui = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
$weather_icons = "<link src='http://startyour.club/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />";
$bootstrap = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css\">
        <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js\"></script>
        <script src=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>";

$navbar = "<nav class= \"navbar navbar-default\">
        <div class=\"container-fluid\">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class=\"navbar-header\">
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"navbar-toggle collapsed\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
<span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>
                    <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>
                    <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>
                </button>
                <a class=\"navbar-brand\" href=\"#\">Project</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class=\"collapse navbar-collapse\" id=\"bs-example-navbar-collapse-1\">
                <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">
                    <li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">Home <span class=\"sr-only\">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href=\"#\">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href=\"#\">Weather</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>";
$navbar_for_weather = "<nav class= \"navbar navbar-default\">
        <div class=\"container-fluid\">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class=\"navbar-header\">
                <button type=\"button\" class=\"navbar-toggle collapsed\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
<span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>
                    <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>
                    <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>
                </button>
                <a class=\"navbar-brand\" href=\"#\">Project</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class=\"collapse navbar-collapse\" id=\"bs-example-navbar-collapse-1\">
                <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">
                    <li><a href=\"#\">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=\"#\">News</a></li>
                    <li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">Weather <span class=\"sr-only\">(current)</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>";
$cnnNewsHeader = "<div class=\"col-sm-4\" style=\"margin-left: 65%; margin-top: 2.5%;\">
            <div class=\"panel panel-default\">
                <div class=\"panel-heading\">
Cnn News
</div>
                <div class=\"panel-body\">
                        <div class=\"list-group\">";

$cnnNewsFooter = "</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
```

Which basically defines many variables to use in my main pages.

And my **resources/dragable.js** is:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".panel" ).draggable();
});
```

And also my **weatherFetcherForIndex.js** is as follows:

```
/**
 * Created by root on 11/7/15.
 */
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
function GetLocation(location) {
    var long = location.coords.longitude;
    var lat = location.coords.latitude;
    $.post("weatherModule/jsPhpInterface.php", {lat: lat, lon: long})
        .done(function (data) {
            var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#temp").html
            (
                "<div class='panel panel-primary'>" +
                "<div class='panel-heading'>" +
                "Temperature" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='panel-body'>"
                +
                parsedJSON.data.current_condition[0].FeelsLikeC + "° C" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>"
            );
        });
}
```

And When I open up my `index.php` I get the news panel dragable, but the weather panel is not dragable. Any Help Would be Very Appreciated!!!!

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 1):

As you have specified, your selector for draggable content is `panel` class:

```
$( ".panel" ).draggable();
```

But your weather panel doesn't have a `panel` class. You must select your weather panel with proper class name or add `panel` class name to weather panel.

---

**Update:**

Because you're creating weather panel on the fly you must make it draggable after creating it. After adding your weather panel to DOM you must make it draggable with `$(".panel").draggable();`.

Add it after changing `html` content of the `temp` element:

```
$("#temp").html
(
    "<div class='panel panel-primary'>" +
    "<div class='panel-heading'>" +
    "Temperature" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class='panel-body'>"
    +
    parsedJSON.data.current_condition[0].FeelsLikeC + "° C" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>"
);
$('.panel').draggable();
```

Comment: But I have that `panel` class in the my weather panel, it is defined in **`weatherFectherForIndex.js`**

Comment: I have updated my answer. Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: A little foolish thing lately, where should i add it?

Comment: Well, It is not working still now. But could you apply your suggested way in my project repo, https://github.com/gourabNagDev/home. That would be very appreciated.

Comment: @GourabNag your mistake is that you have added the `$('.panel').draggable();` after function definition. You must add it inside the function immediately after `$('#temp').html(...)` function call, just like the code in the answer.